# Trying to understand the derivation in the Information Bottleneck Method

Tags: information-theory, mutual-information, derivative

I'm trying to understand the proofs on the [The information bottleneck method](https://arxiv.org/abs/physics/0004057) paper by Tishby, Pereira and Bialek without luck.  In particular, the second term in the functional derivative of the Mutual Information, i.e.,
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial p(\tilde{x} | x)} I(X, \tilde{X}) = \frac{\partial}{\partial p(\tilde{x} | x)} \left[ \sum_{x, \tilde{x}} p(\tilde{x} | x) p(x) \big( \log p(\tilde{x} | x) - \log p(\tilde{x}) \big) \right].
$$

In the equations 10 and 25, when they take the functional derivative $\frac{\partial}{\partial p(\tilde{x} | x)} \sum_{x, \tilde{x}} p(\tilde{x} | x) p(x) \log p(\tilde{x})$, that is the mutual information $I(X, \tilde{X})$ functional derivative that corresponds to the denominator in the $\log$, they have a different way of finding the derivative that I cannot understand.

In (10),
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial p(\tilde{x} | x)} \sum_{x, \tilde{x}} p(\tilde{x} | x) p(x) \log p(\tilde{x}) = p(x) \left[ \log p(\tilde{x}) + \frac{1}{p(\tilde{x})} \sum_{x'} p(x') p(\tilde{x} | x') \right].$$
But shouldn't the second term $\sum_{x'} p(x') p(\tilde{x} | x')$ be the functional derivative of this w.r.t. $p(\tilde{x} | x)$ due to the chain rule.  Additionally, I think it is missing the $p(\tilde{x} | x)$ from the first product rule.  (See my attempt of this derivation below.)  In (25), they do something similar (I guess), since the term accompanying $\log p(\tilde{x})$ is $1$.

My attempt is
$$\begin{align}
\frac{\partial}{\partial p(\tilde{x} | x)} \sum_{x, \tilde{x}} p(\tilde{x} | x) p(x) \log p(\tilde{x}) &= p(x) \left[ \log p(\tilde{x}) + \frac{p(\tilde{x} | x)}{p(\tilde{x})} \frac{\partial p(\tilde{x})}{\partial p(\tilde{x} | x)} \right] \\
&= p(x) \left[ \log p(\tilde{x}) + \frac{p(\tilde{x} | x)}{p(\tilde{x})} p(x) \right] \\
&= p(x) \left[ \log p(\tilde{x}) + p(x | \tilde{x}) \right]
\end{align}$$
So, I was wondering if somehow $p(x | \tilde{x})=1$ given the $x$ and $\tilde{x}$ after the functional derivative and due to the relation between $\tilde{x}$ been considered as the quantized version of $x$ (the codeword in the codebook), and if this is the case, why?

What am I doing wrong?